# Using List Behavior how to display an empty list loading data only after search

Tags: octobercms

I'm using the awesome [List Behavior](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists) and now I need to prevent a list from loading data by default.

- The list should be empty when the page loads - no records displayed
- When the user enters search criteria in the search input then the records that match the search term will be displayed

Are there any settings to tell the list controller to not load data upfront?

If overriding the controller index method is required, what's the best practice to follow to check if a search term has been entered and return and empty list?

Answer (score 0):

there are no settings to tell the list controller to not load data on first GET

I think you have to options :

1. You can create a brand new widget, but it will be lot of
   work to make it like listWidget but widget are very easy to create
   as they are about the same as components. **I think this is the best
   way** even if your widget is not as generic as october's default
   one.
2. You can override the controller method listExtendQueryBefore()

```php
    public function listExtendQueryBefore($query, $def = null)
    {

        if(Request::isMethod('GET')) // Make it yours here i show nothing on a GET
         {
            return  $query->where('id','=',0); 
            //filter on an id that doesn't exist or some thing else        
         }   

    }
```

The input from the widget look like this

```php
array (
   'fullToolbarSearch' => //this is the key
        array (
           'term' => 'greg','bee',
        ),
)
```

As you can see method 2 is easy but this is just a workaround solution